# Scala: having issue with a forward reference + looping counter

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I am using the Akka scheduler in order to stagger the sending of messages from a List, built from reading in lines of a file. Here's some code:

```
 def startClock {
          val filename = "conf/my_file.json"
          val lines = scala.io.Source.fromFile(filename).getLines.toList
          var linePtr = 0

          if(linePtr == lines.length) { 
            clock.cancel()
          }
          else {
            Logger.info(s"num: $linePtr")
            default ! Message(lines(linePtr))
            linePtr = linePtr + 1
          }
        }

lazy val clock: Cancellable = Akka.system.scheduler.schedule(Duration.Zero, Duration.create(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))(startClock)
val x = clock
```

Now in order to get around the forward reference compiler error, which looked like the following: `play.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[forward reference extends over definition of value clock]`

I had to set clock to `lazy` and then reference it on the next line in order to trigger `startClock`, and it does that part just fine. The issue I have here is, `linePtr` is always `0`. It is never incrementing yet the the code in the `else {}` block is confirmed always hitting. I essentially just have infinite recursion here and I'm not familiar enough with Scala to identify what I did wrong here. I've also tried defining the val `clock` before `startClock` but then I have a forward reference in the inverse scenario as well. Seems like a chick and egg problem here.

Comment: One issue I can see is that `linePtr` is defined as being local to the `startClock` function.  Each time `startClock` is invoked by the scheduler, it always sets `linePtr` to 0 so that's why it always hits your else statement.  If you want to properly increment then you probably should define `filename`, `lines`, and `linePtr` outside of the `startClock` function.  This would be messy code in that it's very "side effecty" but it would be a step in the right direction for what you want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the lesson is not about how variable capture works, but about using API.  Since `getLines` gives you an iterator, just use it to iterate. Speculatively:

```
val lines = Source.fromFile(f).getLines
val clock = scheduler schedule send
def send  = if (lines.hasNext) d ! Message(lines.next) else clock.cancel()
```